# Ada: float instantiation from another package

Tags: floating-point, instantiation, ada

I'm trying to create a new Float type with 6 digits precision. But it seems that I'm not able to use it. Here's the code from the package MyFloat_IO.ads

```
WITH Ada.Text_IO;

PACKAGE MyFloat_IO IS

TYPE MyFloat IS DIGITS 6 RANGE 0.0..Float'Last;
PACKAGE MyFloat_IO IS NEW Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO(MyFloat);

end MyFloat_IO;
```

and the main code:

```
WITH Ada.Text_IO;
WITH MyFloat_IO;
USE MyFloat_IO;
WITH Ada.Numerics;


PROCEDURE TEST2 IS

X : MyFloat := 3.5;
Y : CONSTANT := Ada.Numerics.Pi;
Z : MyFloat;


BEGIN -- main program
  Z := X * Y;
  MyFloat_IO.Put(Z);
  Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
END TEST2;
```

On compiling I get the error message:

```
14. BEGIN -- main program
15.     Z := X * Y;
16.     MyFloat_IO.Put(Z);
                  |
    >>> "Put" not declared in "MyFloat_IO"

17.     Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
18. END TEST2;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot...

---

Update: new code as per the suggestions of T.E.D:

1. package MyFloat_I0.ads :

   ```
   WITH Ada.Text_IO;
   PACKAGE MyFloat_I0 IS
   TYPE Instance IS DIGITS 6 RANGE 0.0..Float'Last;
   PACKAGE MyFloat IS NEW Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO(Instance);
   end MyFloat_I0;
   ```
2. and the main code :

   ```
   WITH Ada.Text_IO;
   WITH MyFloat_I0;
   use MyFloat_I0;
   WITH Ada.Numerics;

   PROCEDURE TEST2 IS


   X : Instance := 3.5;
   Y : CONSTANT := Ada.Numerics.Pi;
   Z : Instance;


   BEGIN -- main program
     Z := X * Y;
     MyFloat.Instance.Put(Z);
     Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
   END TEST2;
   ```

On compilation I get:

```
MyFloat.Instance.Put(Z);
               |
    >>> "Instance" not declared in "MyFloat"
```

Comment: The compilation error is because you have the wrong name for your package. For a full explanation, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that you declared a package named MyFloat_IO (derived from Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO) **inside of** another package also named MyFloat_IO. In order to get at it the way you have things declared, you would have to call:

```
MyFloat_IO.MyFloat_IO.Put(Z);
```

I'm pretty sure it is possible to just derive a package from a generic by itself as a compilation unit. However, you might consider instead renaming the package `MyFloat`, the type something like `Instance`, and your IO package `IO`. That way, people looking to use it will say `MyFloat.Instance` for the type and `MyFloat.IO` for the IO package.

(Update answer)

I can see from the code you posted I must have confused you thoroughly. Here's what I had in mind (warning: not compiled).

```
package MyFloat is
   type Instance is digits 6 range 0.0..Float'Last; --'

   package IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO (Instance);
end MyFloat;
```

In other words, the package is named `MyFloat`, the type is named `Instance`, and the IO package is named `IO`. When called from outside the package, the type is `MyFloat.Instance`, and the put routine is `MyFloat.IO.Put`.

Note that if you are using Gnat, you will have to rename the source file when you rename the package.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did what you wrote in the second paragraph of your answer i.e. now I have MyFloat_I0.Instance.Put(Z) but on compiling I get >>invalid prefix in selected component "INSTANCE". There is still something wrong. I have changed package MyFloat to Instance and renamed MyFloat_IO to MyFloat_I0 with an ending zero digit.

Comment: You wrote: MyFloat.Instance .But MyFloat doesn't exist anymore as we have renamed it to Instance. Or are you asking me to use a generic package? It's a bit unclear to me, Thanks.

Comment: `MyFloat` will be the package name. If `Instance` is the name of your type inside the package, then from outside the package you would refer to it as `MyFloat.Instance`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things out. I'm still not getting it right. I've put my new code at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Your first solution i.e MyFloat_IO.MyFloat_IO.Put(Z) works. 1 vote up. It would be great if I could to make your other solution work too.

Comment: Thanks for your very kind help. It works fine. Yes I was confused but now I can see the logic in what you wrote and it makes sense. This "example" is a very good illustration of package referencing for Ada beginners. I was confusing the package with the type as you have noticed.